# How do I subset by the ranges of two variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, between

I have two continuous variables Light and Temperature and I am studying rates of photosynthesis against these variables.

I am looking to split/subset my data into small ranges of light and temperature which I will then plot photosynthesis against.

I was wondering how can I split up my data into these light and temperature range combinations. For example, I would like the following:

Dataset1: (Light >100 & <200) & (Temperature >15 and <20)

Dataset2: (Light >100 & <200) & (Temperature >20 and <25)

... etc. which will be continued for each light range and each temperature range.

I want to specify that I am only interested in the subsetting of my data by temperature and light.
This is because I will be plotting the data in that data set by another measured variable (Photosynthesis). I am not looking to plot light or temperature itself.

My outcome: Calculate average photosynthesis in two treatments (ambient CO2 and elevated CO2) in these different microclimate ranges.

So far I have tried:
subset() 
%inrange%
%between%

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Quite broad question. Could you please make some effort and give a [**MVCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The `cut` function might be what you are looking for?

Comment: @jay.sf I don't have any code, that is my problem. I can provide some data but I really do not know what code to be using to subset my data into these sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of the base function `cut` and the ggplot function `facet_wrap` you can do what you need plus have the flexibility of trying out multiple arrangements and without the proliferation of multiple data frames.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- expand.grid(light = seq(100,300, by = 25),
                 temperature = seq(15,25, by = 2))

df_cat <- df %>%
  mutate(light.level = cut(light, 
                           breaks = c(100,200,300), 
                           include.lowest = T, 
                           labels = c("dim", "bright")),
         temperature.level = cut(temperature, 
                                 breaks = c(15,20,25), 
                                 include.lowest = T, 
                                 labels = c("cool", "warm")))

ggplot(df_cat, aes(x = light, y = temperature, colour = temperature.level, shape = light.level)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~temperature.level + light.level)
```

[image: Facet wrap based on cuts in light and temperature values]

Comment: @Autumnoak, did this work for you? I think the answer is sufficiently different from those in the linked post as this deals specifically with implementation in ggplot2

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am very new to this so please excuse the stupid question... But where/how do I use my own data set for this. I am not sure where about in the code it is to be located. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df` is a placeholder for your data; `df_cat` is a placeholder for your edited data where it has been cut according to your light and temperature range combinations.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll see how I get on.